# In Laravel I want change column type to double from varchar it gives error. But while creating column it works correctly

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
Schema::table('products', function($table) {

    $table->double('sales_price')->change();
});
```

Comment: Gives error regarding double not found in "doctrine/dbal".

Comment: Please include that error message in your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50815583/edit) and remove your comment. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: pls always response with the green check and upvoting if any answer help you, you should accept as an answer of @jainam shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doctrine/dbal not support double on changes. you can use decimal instead of double.

```
Schema::table('products', function ($table) {
    $table->decimal('sales_price', 8, 6)->change();
});
```